# How to determine the baseline for various operations based on hardware specs?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, hardware, embedded-linux

I have an embedded linux device and I would like to know the baseline for various operations on the device for e.g. memory read , memory write, movinand read and write etc. Is there a way to find the baseline speeds for these operations on the device ?

Comment: What do you mean by "baseline?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the datasheets for the various devices and do some math.

For example, if you have 32 bit SDRAM running at 50MHz, with CAS latencies of 4-1-1-1, and you can burst, then you know it will take 7 clocks to transfer 4 words (16 bytes). There will probably be an idle period of 1 clock also, so it's really 8 clocks for the 16 bytes, or 2 bytes for every clock, which at 50MHz is 100MB/s. Now, you should really subtract the time it spends refreshing the memory, etc.

There's really no way to know what the performance should be without reading specs and doing the math.